# How to make a https POST Web Request to RESFULL API?

Tags: api, http, https

I need to make a webrequest with HTTPS URL. But it always return (403) error. is there any other way for HTTPS URLs?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    dataMap := map[string]interface{}{} // own map
    data, err := json.Marshal(dataMap)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything", bytes.NewBuffer(data)) // replace url
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    resp, err := (&http.Client{}).Do(req) // send request
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body) // read body
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var jsonResp map[string]interface{} // response map
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &jsonResp)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Response: %s\nStatus: %s\n", jsonResp, resp.Status)
}
```

The output was:

> Response: map[status:error code:apiKeyMissing message:Your API key is missing. Append this to the URL with the apiKey param, or use the x-api-key HTTPheader.]
>
> Status: 401 Unauthorized

There still is an error, but that is caused by the server, because there is no API key.